# Dictionary Boxing

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm using the **Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0** as a template for my project.

In this project I have a base class for all entities, projectiles, et cetera, called `Sprite`.

I am planning to use a singleton to handle all of the `Sprite`s so I don't have to create a new `Sprite` every time I need it if it has been used before.

This is preferred since `Sprite`s have a `Texture2D` field among other fields that could eat up memory, given enough `Sprite`s are created.

Here is part of my `Texture2D` singleton as a reference:

```
public static class TextureManager{
    private static Dictionary<string, Texture2D> allTextures = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();
    public static Texture2D GetTexture(string name){
        if(allTextures.ContainsKey(name))
            return allTextures[name];

        ... //Code to handle and create a new key is omitted for simplicity's sake

        return newTexture; //The new texture created from the "name" key
    }
}
```

This singleton is preferred over just creating the new `Texture2D` from the content pipeline every time it is needed.  The code was derived from [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/98698).

When planning the `Sprite` singleton, it occurred to me that boxing would have to occur for the singleton to work on one `Dictionary`, since essentially all of my entity and projectile classes would inherit the `Sprite` class.

**QUESTION:**

Is boxing/unboxing on one `Dictionary` more efficient than having multiple `Dictionary`s for each type of `Sprite`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not boxing...

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or
>   to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the CLR
>   boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object and
>   stores it on the managed heap. Unboxing extracts the value type from
>   the object. Boxing is implicit; unboxing is explicit. The concept of
>   boxing and unboxing underlies the C# unified view of the type system
>   in which a value of any type can be treated as an object.

Boxing happens when a value of value type is converted to a reference type. Casting a reference type to its base type is **not** boxing/unboxing.

Casting isn't very expensive, though it will incur a cost, as will a `switch` statement, or a `typeOf` or any other method.

In short, you will have to perform benchmarks to really get to the bottom of your problem for micro-optimization. However, i think storing as base type would be fine in my opinion.

---

**Additional resources**

- [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#performance)
- [.NET Performance Tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/performance-tips)

Comment: if i were to store a derived class object into a base class `Dictionary` `TValue` or a `List<T>` `T`, could i still retrieve the derived class object *as a derived class object*?  if so, what should i use to retrieve it?

Comment: @Tau You would have to cast it back, i am assuming you know the type you want on retrieval. also note, Dictionary is not thread safe